# php Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context

Tags: php

this php row

```
if ($this->config->get('refprogram_sharing_enable') && !empty($this->config->get('refprogram_sharing_links'))) {
```

returns error message
Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context

Comment: this code seems to be alright, problem will be in other part of code

Comment: Please paste the code around this line. This line seems to be fine, so the issue must be on the line before or after.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a version of PHP older than 5.5, you can only use variables within `empty`, and not method calls, otherwise it will throw the error you have received.

A solution would be to calculate the return value first, for example:

```
$links = $this->config->get('refprogram_sharing_links');

if ($this->config->get('refprogram_sharing_enable') && !empty($links)) {
```

Depending on the output of your `get` method, you could also try

`&& $this->config->get('refprogram_sharing_links') !== false`

Hard to tell if this would work without seeing the rest of your code, though.

Answer (score 0):

In case if the first variable is string and the second is array:

```
$refprogram_sharing_enable = $this->config->get('refprogram_sharing_enable');
$refprogram_sharing_links = $this->config->get('refprogram_sharing_links');

if ( $refprogram_sharing_enable!='' && !empty($refprogram_sharing_links)) {

}
```